# How to change textbox values dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to change dynamically TextBox values. 
i did this but its not working.

```
private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(txtRate.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(txtQty.Text));
}
```

Comment: You are not using the return value of your statement.

Comment: i mean when price and qty will be entered then txtPrice should display the result of txtrate * txtqty.

Comment: So, when you type in a price in a textbox, you want the event handler to replace what you just typed in with a new calculation?  Seems a bit odd to do it that way.

Comment: how i can use the return value of my statement?

Comment: yes i exactly want that. ..sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
    private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          int rate = 0;
          int qty = 0;

          Int32.TryParse(txtRate.Text, out rate);
          Int32.TryParse(txtQty.Text, out qty);

          int total = rate * qty

          // Set the new textBox value
          // txtTotal should be your textbox value (what you have called it)
          txtTotal.Text = total.toString()
    }
```

I´m not a native C# developer so there might be some adjustments in the syntax.

Comment: this code is not working dude

Comment: txtPrice textbox (where i want result to be shown) is read only. is it matters?

Comment: i dont know user2893289.

Comment: You can add and read whatever value you want. Just change the first parameter in Int32.TryParse. So if you want to read txtPrice.Text you could do: int price = 0; Int32.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price);

Comment: thanks alot guys specially user2893289. ur code solve my input string issue.

Answer (score 1):

As dotctor inferred, you're performing an operation but leaving it lost in space. You need to do something like this:

```
String valToChange;
private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     valToChange = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(txtRate.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(txtQty.Text));
}
```

It's not clear which textbox value you want to change, though: you're using the changed event of txtPrice, so if you change that like this:

```
private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(txtRate.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(txtQty.Text));
}
```

...you will have a problem with the same event being called when you change that value. That's why I just put a "valToChange" there. You will have to adjust as needed.

Comment: following code is working but on selecting item name it shows input string was not in a format. but for once it calculates the desired values.int r = int.Parse(txtRate.Text);
            int q = int.Parse(txtQty.Text);
      txtPrice.Text = (r * q).ToString();

Comment: Can you add that code as an update to your question? What do you mean, "was not in a format"?

Comment: error is input string was not in a format. so i tried both methods convert.toint and int.parse. but same error.

Comment: Are you sure - simply "not in a format"?

Comment: ya it was like input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a handler for `TextChanged` event of both `txtQty` and `txtRate`;

```
private void txtQty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePrice();
}

private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePrice();
}

//code from user2893289 answer
private void UpdatePrice()
{
      int r = 0, q = 0;
      int.TryParse(txtRate.Text, out r);
      int.TryParse(txtQty.Text, out q);
      txtPrice.Text = (r*q).toString()
}
```

You should favor using `int.TryParse` over `Convert.ToInt32` because `Convert.ToInt32` will throw exception if input string format is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
double rate = Convert.ToDouble(txtRate.Text);
int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
txtPrice.Text = ((double)rate*qty).ToString();
```

It assumes that txtRate contains a value such as "3.00" and that txtQty contains a value such as "7"

### UPDATE

Since the rate is "readonly" this might be a better way to do it:

```
const double RANA_RASHIDS_RATE = 3.14; // or whatever it should be
. . .
txtRate.Text = RANA_RASHIDS_RATE.ToString(); // this is just for show
double rate = RANA_RASHIDS_RATE;
int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
txtPrice.Text = ((double)rate*qty).ToString();
```

### UPDATE 2

Make sure there's a value in txtQty, or use a fake value (1):

```
const double RANA_RASHIDS_RATE = 3.14; // or whatever it should be
. . .
txtRate.Text = RANA_RASHIDS_RATE.ToString(); // this is just for show
double rate = RANA_RASHIDS_RATE;
int qty = 1;
if (!txtQty.Text.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
{
    qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
}
txtPrice.Text = ((double)rate*qty).ToString();
```

There are other things you could do, if you want to get "fancy," such as monitor the change event of txtQty and only allow numerical values and backspace to be entered. That is left as an exercise for the questioner, though.

Comment: this code works when i write something in txtRate.

Comment: i want to view result without typing in txtrate.because txtrate is readonly textbox

Comment: You can mark it as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: You don't need to type into it; you can set the value at design time. The code will work whether the value is readonly or not. In fact, I would do it a little differently in that case. I will update this answer.

Comment: ur updated code workds fine B. Clay Shannon. i just wrote that code in txtqty textbox.,rathe than txtprice. thanks alot man

Comment: B. Clay Shannon! when i put values it shows result perfectly but when i backspace the values in txtquanty textbox it shows following error.Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: You'll have to add code to make sure that it works on some value if the box is empty.